# how to create dynamic sidebar ( menu ) for unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to create a sidebar (like nav drawer in android) for my AR Unity app, when I touch left border of screen and drag to right, a sidebar should appear with a list of buttons such as (settings, about us..).

Comment: I recommend splitting this in 2 separate questions

Answer (score 2):

Just something quick I whipped up. This should get you started.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SlidePanel : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Process touch for panel display on if the touch is less than this threshold.
    private float leftEdge = Screen.width * 0.25f;

    //Minimum swipe distance for showing/hiding the panel.
    float swipeDistance = 10f;


    float startXPos;
    bool processTouch = false;
    bool isExpanded = false;
    public Animation panelAnimation;



    void Update(){
        if(Input.touches.Length>0)
            Panel(Input.GetTouch(0));
    }




    void Panel (Touch touch)
    {
        switch (touch.phase) {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            //Get the start position of touch.

            startXPos = touch.position.x;
            Debug.Log(startXPos);
            //Check if we need to process this touch for showing panel.
            if (startXPos < leftEdge) {
                processTouch = true;
            }
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Ended:
            if (processTouch) {
                //Determine how far the finger was swiped.
                float deltaX = touch.position.x - startXPos;


                if(isExpanded && deltaX < (-swipeDistance))
                {

                    panelAnimation.CrossFade("SlideOut");
                    isExpanded = false;
                } 
                else if(!isExpanded && deltaX > swipeDistance) 
                {
                    panelAnimation.CrossFade("SlideIn");
                    isExpanded = true;
                }

                startXPos = 0f;
                processTouch = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I tried to add animation to the script inspector, it doesn't take it and remains empty!
how can I solve that?

Comment: Just drag and drop the game object which has the  Animation component to this script in the inspector. Note: It uses legacy animation (not Animator);

Comment: how to create legacy animation?
I used Window-> animation to create the animation but I cannot drag and drop it into the script inspector.
I don't know if I used the correct method!

Comment: 1) Add animation component to the Panel you want to animate. 2) Windows->Animation to create the animations. If you do not do 1, by default Unity will create animations that are compatible with Animator and not Legacy Animation. 3) After making the animation, drag and drop the PANEL to the script inspector.

Comment: For more information, I highly suggest going through the Unity basics at https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/editor/game-objects-and-components?playlist=17090

Comment: I did these steps, When I try to add the animation, the one I created is shown in the window "select animation" but when I try to select it, it was not selected!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87994/discussion-between-mohamad-and-puneet).

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ToggleInfo : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject panel;
int counter;

public void toggle()
{
    counter++;
    if(counter%2==1)
    {
        panel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
  }
}
```

> 1. Make sure that the name of the Panel is '**panel**' in the inspector and it is **initially disabled**.
>
> 2.Attach this script to the button, and drag your '**panel**' into the public gameobject of the script in the inspector panel.
>
> 3.Call the **toggle function** from the button onclick.